# plotting average by each genres; pandas

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
df = df.dropna(subset=['genres']).reset_index(drop=True) 

splitted = df['genres'].str.split('|')  
l = splitted.str.len()

x = df['gross'] / df['budget']

df = pd.DataFrame({x: np.repeat(df[x], l), 'genres':np.concatenate(splitted)}) 



d = {'mean':'Average Income'}
df1 = df.groupby('genres')[x].agg(['mean']).rename(columns=d) 

df1.plot.bar() 

plt.yscale("log") 
plt.xlabel("Genre")
```

I want to plot the average of each 'x' for how ever many genres there is[since there are multiple genres for a single movie, I split them into single ones], but I'm not sure what is wrong with my code. It's not doing what I wanted. I need some assistance.

[Here's the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iylY.png)

[image: Jezrael's output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if need aggregate only one function more common is used [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html):

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'genres':['Comedy|Crime|Drama|Thriller','Comedy|Crime|Drama',
                   'Comedy|Crime','Drama|Thriller','Drama','Comedy|Crime'],
                   'gross':[10,20,30,40,50,60],
                   'budget':[3,4,5,3,2,5]})


df = df.dropna(subset=['genres']).reset_index(drop=True) 

splitted = df['genres'].str.split('|')  
l = splitted.str.len()

x = df['gross'] / df['budget']

#is necessary define new column name (divided) and change `df[]` to `x`  
df = pd.DataFrame({'divided': np.repeat(x, l), 'genres':np.concatenate(splitted)}) 
print (df)
      divided    genres
0    3.333333    Comedy
1    3.333333     Crime
2    3.333333     Drama
3    3.333333  Thriller
4    5.000000    Comedy
5    5.000000     Crime
6    5.000000     Drama
7    6.000000    Comedy
8    6.000000     Crime
9   13.333333     Drama
10  13.333333  Thriller
11  25.000000     Drama
12  12.000000    Comedy
13  12.000000     Crime
```

---

```
#define column for aggregate (divided), no x, because processing new df created by repeat 
d = {'mean':'Average Income'}
df1 = df.groupby('genres')['divided'].mean().rename(columns=d).reset_index(name='return')


df1.plot.bar(x='genres', y='return') 

plt.yscale("log") 
plt.xlabel("Genre")
```

[image: graph]

Comment: The graph showed, but the x-axis doesn't have the genres names instead it's numbers.

Comment: posted your output above

Comment: haha different computer. Old one still works Just getting mixed up on the two accounts :P

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you.

Comment: Thank for the big help again!

Comment: Glad can help! If you want, you can accept all old your question - for each accepting get 2 points. Not only my answers but also answers of another people. Thank you very much again and happy coding!

Comment: Oh How do I change that 'None' to 'Return'?

Comment: Check edit. I have to reset index for dataframe and then use plot.bar(x=, y=)